# How do I update valued in a Memory Mapped File in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a proxy process which a number of client applications will connect to using .Net remoting. I would like to manage this proxy's existence by using some reference counting scheme. To do this I thought I would use a small Memory Mapped File in which I will store a key-value (string-int) pair which will look something like this:

> ref_count 2

However, I would like to update the ref_count value from time to time but I'm having problems doing so. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 100))
        {
            bool mutexCreated;
            Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                writer.Write("count:");
                writer.Write(3);
            }
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();

            mutex.WaitOne();
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

                Console.WriteLine("String value is: {0}", reader.ReadString()); 
                Console.WriteLine("UInt32 value is: {0}", reader.ReadUInt32()); 

                // Update mmf data
                writer.Write("count:");
                writer.Write(30);

                // empty string where "count" was expected
                Console.WriteLine("String value is: {0}", reader.ReadString());
                // 0 where 30 was expected
                Console.WriteLine("UInt32 value is: {0}", reader.ReadUInt32()); 
            }
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is, what is the best way to update my reference count and also, why does my second write not work in the above code example?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is a stream.  So reading from it advances the Position.  You'll need to add

```
  stream.Position = 0;
```

both before the code that updates the count *and* the code that reads it again.  Further improve it by not writing the string, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The second Write calls work - but you're writing/reading from the "wrong" location.

After all this is done, you should have in memory:

5 (length of "code:")
"code:" (the actual characters for "code:")
3 (value you wrote/read)
5 (length of "code:")
"code:" (the actual characters for "code:")
30 (value you wrote)
0 (length of the empty string you read)
0 (value you read)

Each call to any of the BinaryReader/BinaryWriter methods is advancing the underlying Stream. It works the first time because you constructed a new stream on the view of the memory mapped file (thus resetting the Stream). Try calling stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin) between the write and the read and seeing what happens.